# How to share an icon between emails?

Tags: email, attachment

There several tutorials which show how to upload note / attachment for particular object http://salesforceworld.blogspot.ie/2011/06/save-attachment-in-apex.html  However, I want to store the same icon as a note / attachment for a selection of custom objects that I end up merging into emails.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Might I suggest you consider making your question more aligned with your goal, e.g. "How to share an icon between emails?"

Comment: @Andrew Fawecett done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachments must be related to a given object record, they cannot be shared. These are some options to consider...

1. You could consider if there is a common related record make the attachment to that and reference that in your emails.
2. Similar to the above, but perhaps create a 'Email Template Settings' custom object, having only one record in it, with custom fields and attachments to items your email template needs.
3. Upload the icon as a Document into a Folder and reference that from your emails, take a look at [this](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/email_template_images.htm). This [blog](http://www.shellblack.com/salesforce/marketing/html-email/) also provides quite a detailed walk through of how to do this.
4. You can also consider using a Static Resource to upload your image, this really depends on how often and who needs to change it. As Mohith has pointed out this will not work for Email templates as the Static Resource is not publicly accessible. Given you have been using Attachments, I'm not sure if this is an issue or not. You can generate a PDF from the email to workaround this.

I think your best bet is option 3 personally. If you are packaging your solution, you cannot hard code the ID's. So this bit of code will generate the URL dynamically for you.

```
Document document = [Select Id, Url From Document Where DeveloperName = 'New'];
String docUrl = document.Url != null ? document.Url : 
      String.format('{0}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id={1}&oid={2}', 
         new String[] { URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(), 
                        document.Id, 
                        UserInfo.getOrganizationId() });
```

**NOTE:** Updated to check with the document has been explicitly given a URL by the end user and uses that instead.

Comment: Static Resource we will not be able to pull image in Visualforce template

Comment: Thanks Mohith, good point, I've updated my answer to clarify. I agree thought option 3 is typically the best.

Comment: @Andrew Facett thanks.  If I use approach number 3, every org that uses my package will have to update the template with the image id and org id.  Is there any other way to reference the image?

Comment: Yes for a packaged solution you need to be dynamic. Let me update my answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

I have SnapShots from my org on how you can upload a document from Your Local.Just Upload and store the Id generated after you upload from URL in custom label and you can follow the document http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/email_template_images.htm to get the image in your Vf template